# Targeting specific items in a @foreach loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have developed a comments editing system in my blog application.

When a user clicks on the page of a select blog post, a @foreach loop iterates through that post's comments and displays each one in the view underneath the Post's main content.

It is also possible for a user to edit a comment's content. User's click an edit button on the comment and a JavaScript function renders its `<textarea>` editable as well as unhides a "save" button. Once edited and the user hits save, a second JavaScript function sends the updated content to a Controller method which updates the relevant comment on the database.

The code I've produced works fine when there is one comment under the blog post, however, when there are multiple comments on the page, the JavaScript is not able to distinguish which comment is referenced - for example, pressing the edit button on one comment makes the save button appear for all comments.

Is there a straightforward way I can encapsulate the JavaScript for each comment?

Or is the best approach to produce unique Ids for each Comment? If so, what would be the best approach?

My code for your reference is below, though please note I am still new to web scripting and any pointers are appreciated.

THE VIEW (RAZOR):

```
@model List<Assignment_3.Models.CommentSubmission

//Blog Post

//Comments
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //Comment information

    //The textarea 
    <textarea rows="10" readonly class="descriptionForm" id="DescriptionText">@item.Body</textarea>

    //The Edit button
    <div style="text-align:right">
            <img class="edit_icon" src=@Url.Content("~/Images/edit.png") alt='edit' height=15 width=15 />
         <br />

    //The Save button once editing is complete
         <button type="submit"class="btn1" style="visibility: hidden">
            <p class="split-btn-name">Save</p>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></p>
         </button>
    </div>
}

<script>

 //Make textarea editable and unhide the edit save button
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit_icon ").click(function () {
        $(".descriptionForm").removeAttr("readonly");
        $(".btn").removeAttr("style");
    });
});

 //Send updated content to Controller and update database
 $(".btn1").click(function () {
    $(".btn1").hide();
    $(".descriptionForm").setAttribute('readonly');
    var text1 = document.getElementById('DescriptionText').value; 
    var url = "/Comments/EditComment?id=@item.Id&s="+ text1;
        $.post(url, null, function (data) {
    });
}); 

</script>
```

THE CONTROLLER:

```
    public void EditComment(int id, string s)
    {
        var cS = _context.CommentSubmissions
         .Where(c => c.Id == id).
         FirstOrDefault();

        //The Comment's text body
        cS.Body = s;

        _context.Entry(cS).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

ANSWER (thanks to Greg):

FORM:

```
                <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
                    <div data-rel="@item.Id">

                        <textarea rows="10" readonly class="textarea">@item.Body</textarea>
                        <div style="text-align:right">

                           <p>
                                Edit <img class="edit_icon" src=@Url.Content("~/Images/edit.png") alt='Edit' height=15 width=15 id="EditIcon" />
                            </p>

                            @*The Save button once editing is complete*@
                            <input type="button" data-input="edit" value="Save" style="visibility: hidden" id="saveButton">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $(".edit_icon").click(function () {
        var container = $(this).closest('.row');
        var id = parent.find('div[data-rel]');
        var content = container.find('.textarea');
        var button = container.find('#saveButton');
        button.removeAttr("style");
        content.focus();
        content.removeAttr('readonly');

    });

    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        var container = $(this).closest('.row');
        var id = container.find('div[data-rel]');
        var content = container.find('.textarea');
        var button = container.find('#saveButton');

        button.hide();
        content.prop('readonly', true);
        var text1 = descriptionForm.value;

        var url = "/Comments/EditComment?id=" + id + "&s=" + text1;
        $.post(url, null, function (data) {
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Every implementation of a comment system I have seen has at least a uniqueID and a parentID field in the DB. If you really think about it, those represent the minimum required to make nodes of anything with parent and child.

Comment: Agree with I.R.R. Giving your comments unique ids would help. This can then be combined with using 'this' to look up said id within the object that is created when the button is clicked. Something like $(this).parent().attr('id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As denoted in the comment, your JavaScript has nothing unique to anchor on.  So it modifies all elements that meet your criteria, to resolve this you can achieve with a unique identifier or structuring your markup better.

In your case, you have a button with a `type="submit"` which will instantly cause a post back.  Not sure if that is indeed your intent, but you could do:

```
@foreach(var content in Model)
{
     <form name="content.Id" action="Blog/Save" method="post">

     </form>
}
```

In this instance, the post back from your submit could directly hit the server.  But, post backs aren't cool.  To rectify via Ajax, you can do.

```
@foreach(var content in Model)
{
     <div class="container">
          <div data-rel="@content.Id">
              <!-- Put form data, or whatever here. -->
               <input type="button" data-input="edit">Edit</input>
          </div>
     </div>
}
```

Now you have a unique value, clean structure, and you can move throughout the hierarchy fairly easy.  So, for JavaScript you could do:

```
function editBlog(element) {
     var container = document.querySelector(element).closest('[data-rel]');
}
```

I believe that is the ideal approach for JavaScript, I'm a custom to jQuery or a framework like Vue.  So double check the syntax.  But in theory, the JavaScript will scale from the button event to the parent node, then retrieve the child id.  Similar mapping or templates can occur, so you can post the data to your action.

Hopefully this helps.

Update:  You may get some domain error, but I hope not.  Anyways, this is a really simple example.

- Container : Simple element to act as a wrapper.
- Row : Allow you to create a row for element structure.
- Column : Will space around, to fit within window.

The point, is the jQuery will recurse up from the button, to the column, to the row, to the section id, to the container.  But, it won't affect any other element on the page.  If the jQuery was changed, to not affect a specific element, for instance:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
     $(this).text('Edit');  // Only this element
     $('button').text('Edit'); // All button elements
});
```

```js
$(function () {
     $('button').click(function () {          
          var container = $(this).parents('.container');
      var id = parent.find('div[data-rel]');
          var rows = parent.find('.row');
          var columns = parent.find('.column');

          alert('The section id: ' + id.val());

          console.log(container.html());
          console.log(id);
          console.table(rows);
          console.table(columns);
     });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px -1px 1px -2px, -1px 2px 1px -2px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  width: 33.3%;
}

.column:last-of-type {
  width: 10%;
}

.column span {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .2rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column label {
  width: 95%;
}

.column button {
  width: 100px;
}

.column input, .column textarea {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div data-rel="1">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="column">
                    <span>
                         <label>Article Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" data-rel="txtArticleName" />
                    </span>
                    
                    <span>
                         <label>Article Date:</label>
                         <input type="text" data-input="txtArticleDate" />               
                    </span>
               </div>
               
               <div class="column">
                    <label>Article Summary:</label>
                    <textarea data-input="txtArticleSummary" rows="5"></textarea>
               </div>
               
               <div class="column">
                    <button name type="button" onclick="return false;">Save</button>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
     <div data-rel="2">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="column">
                    <span>
                         <label>Article Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" data-rel="txtArticleName" />
                    </span>
                    
                    <span>
                         <label>Article Date:</label>
                         <input type="text" data-input="txtArticleDate" />               
                    </span>
               </div>
               
               <div class="column">
                    <label>Article Summary:</label>
                    <textarea data-input="txtArticleSummary" rows="5"></textarea>
               </div>
               
               <div class="column">
                    <button type="button" onclick="return false;">Save</button>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The code works, but you may have security enabled that may not allow it to work.  But the example is the important part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and . All is clear until the JavaScript - where I am a novice. I've attempted to implement your solution in an attempt above under "Edit". Would it please be possible to check that over as I'm not sure how to use the container variable outlined?

Comment: @scribbio if I have time I’ll make a simple example.  With jQuery that works.

Comment: Hi Greg, through your example, I was able to work out a solution - thank you for your time. For anyone coming to this in the future, I used $(this).closest('.row'); in order to relate the elements I needed to manipulate to the nearest ".row" div, as in Greg's first example. I've put the answer to my particular challenge in the question.

Comment: Glad you got it.